# How to limit access to usb port on PC?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, nodejs, restricted-access

I want to know if it's possible to configure usb port so that it allows you to read only files with a certain extension from the inserted usb flash drive?
I want to exclude any action except reading a file with a certain extension from any inserted usb flash drive.

For e.g. it should prevent the installation of any drivers or whatever, also prevent to use usb keyboards or any usb devices except usb flash drive.

The reason for such a requirement is the placement of the custom vending machine with usb port in a public place.
I want to know how to minimize the risk of attack via usb port.
Will it help in this case the use of some virtual machine?

I want to use ubuntu and node js as a program part.

Comment: There's no risk unless you allow it. By default, a Linux user is NOT ROOT. As such, no one else can install any software or change the OS in any way without the root password. Your approach is nonsense and not doable. What you want to prevent is already provided in the security model.

Comment: I'm so sorry for such a noob question. So if I write a program with node js that will scan files with a certain extension on the inserted USB flash drive, then nothing happens if someone inserts a 4g modem or usb mouse/keyboard or something else instead of simple usb flash drive?

Comment: If you use the ubuntu guest account it is further locked down by apparmor.

Comment: Not "nothing happens if someone inserts a 4g modem or usb mouse/keyboard or something else instead of simple usb flash drive", but "the system will take its (configurable) standard action if someone inserts a 4g modem or usb mouse/keyboard or something else instead of simple usb flash drive".

Comment: Okay, thank you for enlightening a noob like me. So, how to configure system standard action for usb devices? Is it possible to recognize type of usb device and prohibit everything except flash drives?